# How old is the Grinch?

Tags: dr-seuss, grinch

There seem to be some discrepancies on how old the Grinch is during the events of "How the Grinch Stole Christmas".

The [Seuss Fandom Wiki](https://seuss.fandom.com/wiki/The_Grinch#:%7E:text=He%20was%208%20when%20he,1957%20in%20the%202018%20Movie.&text=The%20Grinch%20makes%20a%20cameo%20on%20Margo%27s%20shirt%20in%20Despicable%20Me%203) has his age as "53" but also mention "61" in it's Trivia section with the following explanation:

> He was 8 when he went to Mt Crumpit and he spent 53 years there so at the time of the story he is 61 Years Old Making Him Born in 1896 in the book, 1905 in the 1966 Movie, 1939 in the 2000 Movie, and 1957 in the 2018 Movie.

From a copy of the book, his age when he went to Mt. Crumpit isn't mentioned; it seems to be an addition for the purposes of the movies.

The Wikipedia Entry for [How the Grinch Stole Christmas!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/How_the_Grinch_Stole_Christmas!) mentions the following about the connection with Dr. Seuss:

> Some writers, including Dr. Seuss, have made a connection between the Grinch and Dr. Seuss. In the story, the Grinch laments that he has had to put up with the Whos' celebration of Christmas for **53 years**. As both Thomas Fensch and Charles Cohen note, **Dr. Seuss was 53** when he wrote and published the book. Dr. Seuss asserted the connection in an article in the December 1957 edition of Redbook: *"I was brushing my teeth on the morning of the 26th of last December when I noticed a very Grinch-ish countenance in the mirror. It was Seuss! So I wrote about my sour friend, the Grinch, to see if I could rediscover something about Christmas that obviously I'd lost."*
>
> Seuss's step-daughter, Lark Dimond-Cates, stated in a speech in 2003, *"I always thought the Cat... was Ted on his good days, and the Grinch was Ted on his bad days."* Cohen notes that Seuss drove a car with a license plate that read "GRINCH".

I am inclined to think that 53 years old is the correct age, but was wondering if there was more definitive sources pointing one direction or the other.

Comment: In the most recent film, it's stated that he's eight in the flashback ("[You're 8 years old and you have a beard!](https://getyarn.io/yarn-clip/7ab254fc-4736-4652-b745-43fef1c6efca)"). He appears to have fled to the mountain shortly thereafer.

Comment: In the original story he states that he's put up with Christmas for 53 years. It doesn't state that that's how long he's been up the mountain; *"Why for fifty-three years I've put up with it now! I must stop Christmas from coming! But how?"*. I'm inclined to believe that he's 53.